# c# WPF Xdocument load file on a network

Tags: c#

I am using linq to xml to load an xml file. This file is on my home network.

Full path to xml document:

> "\\FREEBOX\Disque dur\WpfDatabase\Airports.xml"

Path with mapped drive:‪

> "X:\WpfDatabase\Airports.xml"

I am not able to load the document due to error on path format. I've not found any valid solution

Here is a sample of my buggy code to load my xml file:

```
XDocument dataDoc = XDocument.Load(@"\\‪X:\\WpfDatabase\Airports.xml");
return from airport in dataDoc.Descendants("Airport")

                   select new AirportModel
                   {
                       Oaci = airport.Attribute("oaci").Value,
                       Lat = double.Parse(airport.Attribute("lat").Value),
                       Lon=  double.Parse(airport.Attribute("lon").Value)
                   };
```

I hope you can help to resolve this path format.

waiting for your help
brgds
Cyrille

[path of the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR0x9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand it looks like your path string is formatted wrong. You prefix the literal with @, which means the backslashes will be inserted exactly as shown. So you will get the double backslash in front of and after the X:.

If it is a mapped drive, the format would be `@"X:\WpfDatabase\Airports.xml"`. If you are using the UNC path, it would be `@"\\FREEBOX\Disque dur\WpfDatabase\Airports.xml"`.

If you omit the @, you have to escape the backslashes so it would be `"X:\\WpfDatabase\\Airports.xml"` or `"\\\\FREEBOX\\Disque dur\\WpfDatabase\\Airports.xml"`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Your solution work perfectly